# Accordion with pure javascript - expanding does not follow by group

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an accordian and only expand by group during onclick function. So when click on Level 2(1), only div for Level 3(1) is allowed be to expanded. You may take a look at my snippet for clearer understanding. Currently it only worked on Level 2(1).

This is the flow I want:

Click Main Level - Show all the Level 2

Click Level 2(1) - Show all Level 3(1) (if any)

Click Level 2(2) - Show all Level 3(2) (if any)
and etc....

This is what I want for the output:

[image: This is what I want:]

```js
function toggle(item) {
  item.classList.toggle("active");
  let panel = item.nextElementSibling;
  if (panel !== null) {
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.accordion,
.subpanel-accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  display: flex;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panelaccordion {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-accordion {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex: 50%;
}

.button-accordion {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion" id="main-1" onclick="toggle(this);">Level 1</div>
<div class="panelaccordion level2">
  <div class="accordion" id="sub-1" onclick="toggle(this);">
    <div class="text-accordion">Level 2(1)</div>
    <div class="button-accordion" onclick="getid(\'sub-1\');">Click level 2(1)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="subpanel-accordion" id="subpanel-1">
    <div class="text-accordion">Level 3(1)</div>
    <div class="button-accordion" onclick="getidsub(\'subpanel-1\');">Click level 3(1)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion" id="sub-2">
    <div class="text-accordion">Level 2(2)</div>
    <div class="button-accordion" onclick="getid(\'sub-2\');">Click level 2(2)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="subpanel-accordion" id="subpanel-2">
    <div class="text-accordion">Level 3(2)</div>
    <div class="button-accordion" onclick="getidsub(\'subpanel-2\');">Click level 3(2)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion" id="sub-3">
    <div class="text-accordion">Level 2(3)</div>
    <div class="button-accordion" onclick="getid(\'sub-2\');">Click level 2(3)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML `details` tag for accordions. 
I'm adding a small example  [repl](https://repl.it/@bgopikrishna/SpecializedCarpalTelephones)

[MDN HTML details Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details)